# focal-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi.img.xz fails to boot due to missing initrd.img and vmlinuz files

Tags: boot, 20.04

For the last few days the 'current' 20.04 ubuntu-server image for Raspberry Pi (focal-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi.img.xz) fails to boot as the initrd.img and vmlinuz files are missing from the system-boot partition within the image.

Please can someone point me to the right place where I can check if this has already been reported, or where I can report the problem?

Thanks an lot.

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For 20.04 questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 20.04 is 23rd April 2020 when your question will be on-topic here).

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs   (though I usually check via search engine, plus searches using launchpad for existing bugs... if you're unsure you can file a new bug, but it maybe marked a duplicate; so don't take offence (it's easy to miss existing bugs in my experience)).   Thank you for taking the time to report this issue and helping to make Ubuntu better (but please actually file it, this is a user support site)

Comment: Also for best results in bringing it to attention, it should also be reported on the ISO QA tracker (http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/408/builds) so it's reported for the days on which the error occurred; making tracking the patch that caused the issue/regression etc easy to detect; though that tracker will use the launchpad bug ID from my prior comment (on reporting).

Comment: The ".xz" at the end of the file name means that it's compressed and not installed. Return to whatever instructions you were following, redo the steps properly, and look at the output of each step to ensure that no steps resulted in an error message.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback. I posted the issue on the Ubuntu Forums. For completeness the answer is to use the new 20.04 beta release version rather than the focal daily release version. The beta release does have the missing files (initrd.img and vmlinuz).